# Resize a TableView inside a TableViewController Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I have a `TableViewController` which comes from a `TabBarController`. Now my problem is that, the `TableView` becomes scrollable under my `NavigationBar` on the top which is transparent and I don't want this to happen.

The second thing is that the `TableView's` last `cell` goes below the `TabBar` which makes it impossible to select the last cell.

Can someone suggest me how to resize the `TableView`, so that I place it perfectly in between the `navigationBar` on the top and the `TabBar` on the bottom.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Select your UIViewController in storyboard and go to Attribute inspector. In Top Bar combo select Opaque Navigation Bar and in Bottom Bar combo selct Opaque Tab bar.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply. I changed the topBar and the BottomBar to opaque as you said, still the tableview scrolls below the navigationBar and I am not able to select the last cell as It is hidden by the tabBar.

Comment: You may also need to relayout you table view a bit to make it not go below top and bottom bar.